# How to see the contents of a user-provided service?

Tags: cloud-foundry

I'm new to cloud foundry and taking over a configuration that was set up by someone else.  I want to inspect the contents of several user-provided services, to see what values are stored in each one.  But the docs [here](http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/user-provided.html) only tell you how to see ALL the env values bound for an app.  I want to be able to display what is in just ONE of the particular user-provided services.

Answer (score 1):

Try the command on cloudfoundry cli, it'll show services VCAP_SERVICES and environment VCAP_APPLICATION as json :
cf env app-name

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to query the CloudFoundry api endpoint directly to get a list of all user provided service instances. You can find the API documents [here](http://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/) and [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/cc-api-docs/41997426/user_provided_service_instances/list_all_user_provided_service_instances.html) is the precise endpoint you are looking for.

The api endpoint is the same that you at first used when setting up your cf CLI with: `cf api API_ENDPOINT`

If you need to find the auth token for the API request, you can get it from `~/cf/config.json`. It should be in there once you successfully authorized the cf CLI by using `cf login`.